# Book series describing the end of the Age of Reason and the return of magical creatures to the world

Tags: story-identification

Looking to try to identify the name of a series (or its individual books) which I read in the 90's. I've only read the first one/two in the series and I believe that they were still being written at the time I was reading them, though I may be mistaken in this.

The basic premise for the series involved the ending of the "Age of Reason" (I believe they referred to it as such in the books themselves), which allowed the gradual return of magical creatures into the world. Definite presence of at least one Dragon in the books, and the [Tuath(a) Dé Danann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuatha_D%C3%A9_Danann).

I know there was one or more people on a quest, though I cannot remember what the were specifically searching for.

I have the impression of the context of a world unprepared for the return of magic, and a small group of people attempting to prevent it, or at least mitigate the damage it will cause, working with/for the Tuath(a) Dé Danann, though I believe it was somewhat reluctantly, and with the understanding that they had their own goals which were not necessarily friendly.

Comment: Just a note, but the first book, *World's End*, of the series identified in Valorum's answer, was first published in 1999, followed in 2000 by *Darkest Hour*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're describing the [Age of Misrule](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1436393.World_s_End) book series by Mark Chadbourn.

The blurb for the second book ([Darkest Hour](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Darkest_Hour.html?id=E1w0-3yL3fIC&redir_esc=y)) specifically mentions the "end of the age of reason", the return of celtic traditions and the rise of dragons as well as the 'Tuatha de Danaan'.

> On one side stand the Tuatha de Danaan, golden-skinned and beautiful, filled with all the might of angels. On the other are the Fomorii, monstrous devils hell-bent on destroying all human existence. And in the middle are the Brothers and Sisters of Dragons, determined to use the strange power that binds them to the land in a last, desperate attempt to save the human race.

Comment: That sounds familiar... I'll give it a look...

Comment: That's it exactly. Now I know why I couldn't manage to find the proper series - it's actually a set of 3 trilogies. Thanks.